# Comprehensive html5 Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, audio

For the life of me, I cannot find a complete listing of all html5 `<audio>` events and attributes (though I believe they may vary between browsers).  A lot of my googling has websites talking about "using the javascript audio api" or "with the javascript audio api," etc. and shows a couple of examples, but I haven't found a list of methods or what they do.

For example,

```
var a = document.getElementById('audio');
a.ended = function () { alert('foo!'); }; //FAIL
a.onended = function () { alert('foo!'); }; //FAIL
a.addEventListener('ended', function () { alert('foo!'}); }; //PASS
a.addEventListener('play', function () { alert('foo!'}); };
```

Why is there no `onended`?  Why is it called `play` instead of `played`?  These things aren't intuitive, so an actual list of the API would help a lot.

Additionally, do some browsers not respect the above attributes?  My blackberry phone and mobile-ie9 won't alert on the ended event, but chrome, ffx, and ipad-safari all do.

Comment: Support for HTML 5 is still universally pretty bad, and IE isn't exactly notorious for playing nice with standards. A list of the new HTML 5 event handlers for media objects can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp), but I wouldn't expect wide-ranging support for at least a year or two.

Comment: The `<audio>` element and its JavaScript API are relatively new. Support is likely to be variable for some time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [HTML5 spec: the `audio` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-audio-element)
- [When can I use... audio compatibility tables](http://caniuse.com/#search=audio) (and links to external resources)

Unfortunately you're experiencing firsthand the fact that [there simply is no official JavaScript API for audio](http://www.w3.org/2011/audio/wiki/PubStatus) (yet).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from Matt's fine canIuse link

> "Consistant cross-browser support for audio is currently a mess in
>   HTML5 ..."

so you should take a look at sound.js ;)

> "... but SoundJS works to abstract away the problems and makes
>   adding sound to your games or rich experiences much easier. "

[--> Polyfill : SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS)

Answer (score 0):

w3schools has a useful event, property and method list for audio/video. Although it does not address cross browser concerns:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp