# javascript how to check audio load faild

Tags: javascript, audio, event-listener

is there something like

```
var audio=new Audio();

audio.addEventListener("ThisAudioLoadFaild", function(){});
```

Thanks!

By the way, where could I find all the type of audio addEventListeners ?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358624/comprehensive-html5-audio-api?answertab=oldest#tab-top

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Answer (score 0):

you could use error event, like:

```
audio.addEventListener('error', function () {
  console.log('Could not load.');
}, false);
```